# Special properties of binary Galois field

Tags: finite-groups, systems-of-equations, finite-fields

Consider two finite field $A=GF(2^{2k})$ and $B=GF(2^{2n+1})$, where by $GF$ mean Galois field and $k$ and $n$ are two natural number. Assume the following equation
$$
x^2+x+1=0 \tag{1}
$$
*First question:* How to prove that the equation $(1)$ has exactly two solutions in the finite field $A$ and there is no solution for the equation $(1)$ in the Galois field $B$.

*Second question:* Assume the following two condtions

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\sum_{i=1}^4\, \alpha_i=\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3+\alpha_4=0 & &  \\
&&\tag{2} \\
\sum_{i=1}^4\, \alpha_i^5=\alpha_1^5+\alpha_2^5+\alpha_3^5+\alpha_4^5=0 & & 
\end{array}
$$
where $\alpha_i$, $1\leq i \leq 4$, are elements of a finite field. 
How to show that the conditions $(2)$ hold by the four elements of finite field  $A$ but there are no four elements in the finite field $B$ such that satisfy in the conditions $(2)$.

For example, consider the  Galois field $A=GF(2^4)$ that is constructed by the polynomial $\beta^4+\beta^3+1=0$. We can check that the following four elements of finite field $A=GF(2^4)$ hold in the conditions $(2)$:
$$
(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4)=(1,\beta,\beta^2+1,\beta^2+\beta)\,.
$$
Thanks for any suggestion.

**Edition:**

One of the most important matrix in the cryptography is [MDS matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDS_matrix). An interesting method for construction of MDS matrix 
is by [Vandermonde  matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). A vandermonde matrix is defined as follows

\begin{equation}
A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1  & a_1  & a_1^2 & \cdots  & a_1^{n-1}\\
 1  & a_2  & a_2^2 & \cdots  & a_2^{n-1}\\
\vdots    & \vdots    & \vdots  &  \vdots &\vdots    \\
\vdots    & \vdots    & \vdots  &  \vdots &\vdots    \\
 1  & a_{n-1}  & a_{n-1}^2 & \cdots  & a_{n-1}^{n-1}\\
 1  & a_n  & a_n^2 & \cdots  & a_n^{n-1}\\
\end{array}
\right)\, .
\end{equation}

where $a_i$, $1\leq i \leq n$, are elements of $GF(2^{q})$, that is denoted with

$$
A=van(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_n)\, .
$$

It is proved in [this article](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1336783/?reload=true) that if

$$
 A=van(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_n) \quad , \quad B=van(b_1,b_2,\cdots, b_n)\, .
$$

be two vandermonde matrix 
such that $a_i\neq b_j$ for $1\leq i,j \leq n$ then the matrices $A\,B^{-1}$ and $B\, A^{-1}$ are MDS matrices.
Now, consider the following vandermonde matrix of order $4$:

\begin{equation}
C=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1  & \alpha_1  & \alpha_1^2  & \alpha_1^3\\
 1  & \alpha_2  & \alpha_2^2  & \alpha_2^3\\
 1  & \alpha_3  & \alpha_3^2  & \alpha_3^3\\
 1  & \alpha_4  & \alpha_4^2  & \alpha_4^3\\
\end{array}
\right)\, .
\end{equation}

where $\alpha_i$, $1\leq i \leq n$, are elements of $GF(2^{2q})$ and satisfy in the condition $(2)$ and are distinct.
 It can be proved that the inverses of matrix $C$, denoted with $C^{-1}$, can be obtained in the following form

\begin{equation}
C^{-1}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
u\,\alpha_1^3 +u\,v  & u\,\alpha_2^3 + u\,v  & u\, \alpha_3^3 +u\, v   & u\, \alpha_4^3 + u\, v \\
u\, \alpha_1^2  & u\, \alpha_2^2  &u\,  \alpha_3^2   &u\,  \alpha_4^2\\
u\, \alpha_1  & u\, \alpha_2  & u\, \alpha_3 & u\, \alpha_4\\
 u  & u  & u   & u\\
\end{array}
\right)\, .
\end{equation}

where $u$ and $v$ are defined as follows 
$$
u=\sum_{i=1}^4\, \alpha_i^{-3}\quad , \quad v=\sum_{i=1}^4\, \alpha_i^{3}
$$

The last result about the form of $C^{-1}$ matrix,  is part of my research about MDS matrix.

Thanks for all useful comments and answer Professor Jyrki Lahtonen.

Comment: Hint for first question: Note that $f(x) := x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb F_2$. Let $\alpha$ be a root in $f$. What degree does $K := \mathbb F_2(\alpha)$ have, and what field is it isomorphic to? What does this mean for any other extension of $\mathbb F_2$ containing $\alpha$?
For second question: What do you mean by "the" four elements, as $A$ contains $2^{2k}$ elements?

Comment: @johnnycrab I did not understand your hint, is it possible to show that for example why the equation $x^2+x+1$ has no solution in the Galois field  $GF(2^5)$. I mean by "the four elements" is that there are at least four elements in the finite field $GF(2^{2k})$ such that satisfy in the mentioned condition like the example. Thanks for comment.

Comment: Using notation as above, $K := \mathbb F(\alpha)$ is a splitting field of $f$, have $K \cong GF(2^2)$. All finite fields in which $f$ completely decomposes into linear factors must contain $K$, and can thus be seen as extensions of $GF(2^2)$. Which means...

Comment: @johnnycrab Thank you so much for useful comment. Can we say if a finite field has no solution for equation $x^2+x+1$ then dos not satisfy in the second condition?

Comment: For the second question, are there any more conditions? Must all elements be distinct? Certainly the trivial case holds for both cases.

Comment: @johnnycrab all elements have to be distinct, Thanks for comment .I add your note to question as an edition.

Comment: Is this from a coding-theory context? Looks like it might :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Unfortunately no, But can I ask you to explain, why do you think this question looks like to coding theory context? I mean, in which coding subjects, you have seen, similar questions like this question? Thanks for comment.

Comment: It is just that systems of equations such as your $(2)$ are often used to describe error-correcting codes. The non-existence of a set of solutions such that all the variables are distinct is then equivalent to the code not having certain low weight words (usually meaning that we get a better code).

Comment: Actually, I'm more than a bit curious. Can you say something about the context that lead you to system (2)? I can think of coding theoretical and possible also some other combinatorial related constructions. What's yours?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The context of my question comes from cryptography that I will edit my question and mention it. Maybe you right, because one of application of  this method is on the construction of MDS codes. Please wait to edit my question. Thanks.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I edited my question and added some details about context of my question. I hope you find it useful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) relating certain symmetric polynomials to each other (alternatively you can just crank this out with pencil-and-paper work).

If we denote by $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$ the elementary symmetric functions, i.e. the coefficients of
$$
P(x)=(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)(x-\alpha_3)(x-\alpha_4)=x^4+e_1x^3+e_2x^2+e_3x+e_4,
$$
and by $p_i, i\in\Bbb{N},$ the power sum
$$
p_i=\alpha_1^i+\alpha_2^i+\alpha_3^i+\alpha_4^i,
$$
then by the so called Freshman's dream (in characteristic two) we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
p_1&=e_1,\\
p_2&=\alpha_1^2+\alpha_2^2+\alpha_3^2+\alpha_4^2=(\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3+\alpha_4)^2=e_1^2,\\
p_4&=e_1^4,
\end{aligned}
$$
and then a couple of applications of 
Newton's identities eventually give that
$$
p_5=e_1^5+e_2e_1^3+e_3e_1^2+e_2^2e_1+e_2e_3+e_1e_4.\qquad(*)
$$

Your system $(2)$ states that $p_1=e_1=0$ and that $p_5=0$. Plugging in 
$e_1=0$ into $(*)$ then gives the simple consequence
$$
0=p_5=e_2e_3.
$$
So we can conclude that if $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4)$ is a solution of $(2)$ then either $e_3=0$ or $e_2=0$.

Let us first look at the case $e_3=e_1=0$. Then we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(x)&=x^4+e_1x^3+e_2x^2+e_3x+e_4\\
&=x^4+e_2x^2+e_4\\
&=(x^2+\sqrt{e_2}x+\sqrt{e_4})^2,
\end{aligned}
$$
by the Freshman's dream and the fact that in any finite field of characteristic two every element has a (unique) square root. This shows that all the roots of $P(x)$ are double roots contradicting the assumption that the $\alpha_i$s were to be distinct. Observe that this argument works equally well for the field $A$ as well as the field $B$.

The other case $e_2=e_1=0$ is different. This time
$$
P(x)=x^4+e_3x+e_4.
$$
Let us fix the field $K=GF(2^m)$.
The following trick from the theory of linearized polynomials allows us to make progress. Let $L(x)=x^4+e_3x$. Again by Freshman's dream we have
$$
L(a+b)=L(a)+L(b)\qquad(**)
$$
for all $a,b\in K$. If $\alpha_i,i=1,2,3,4,$ are four distinct zeros of $P(x)$, then $L(\alpha_i)=P(\alpha_i)+e_4=e_4$. By $(**)$ this implies that
for all $i=2,3,4$ we have
$$
L(\alpha_i-\alpha_1)=L(\alpha_i)+L(\alpha_1)=e_4+e_4=0.
$$
As $L(0)=0$ the (linearized) polynomial $L(x)$ also has four zeros.
But
$$
L(x)=x(x^3+e_3),
$$
so the non-zero roots of $L(x)$ are exactly the cubic roots of $e_3$. This explains why we get different behavior according to parity of $m=[K:GF(2)]$.
Namely:

- If $m$ is odd, then $3\nmid 2^m-1$. As the group $K^*$ is cyclic of order $2^m-1$ this implies that every element of $K$ has a **unique** cube root in $K$. Applying this to $e_3\in K$ implies that $L(x)$ has exactly two roots in $K$, and therefore $P(x)$ cannot have four roots in $K$ either.
- On the other hand id $m$ is even, then $3\mid 2^m-1$, and the cubes of $K^*$ form a subgroup of index three - each with three cube roots. In this case the polynomial $L(x)$ has four distinct roots in $K$ whenever $e_3$ is a non-zero cube in $K$. Therefore for some choice of $(e_3,e_4)$ the polynomial $P(x)$ has the required four distinct solutions. Consequently system $(2)$ also has solutions of the required type. An easy example is when $\alpha_i,i=1,2,3,4,$ range over the elements of the subfield $GF(4)$. In that case $\alpha_i^5=\alpha_i^2$ and it is easy to check that you get a solution.

Comment: I am sorry , because of my reputation, can not vote to your great answer. Thank you in advance for your attention and the all time you have taken for this question, Professor Jyrki Lahtonen.

Comment: Does your solution is invertible. I mean, if $e_2=0$ than can we conclude that $\sum_{i=1}^4\, \alpha_i^5=0$ or not? In fact, I want to find a simple way to obtain $\alpha_i$'s that satisfy in condition $(2)$, instead of finding by full searching? Thanks.

Comment: @user0410: Yes, that part of the argument also works backwards. If $e_1=e_2=0$ for a set of four distinct elements $\alpha_i\in GF(2^{2k}),i=1,2,3,4$, then you have a solution of (2). I think the argument actually shows that you get all such quadruplets from the following recipe. Let $\omega\in GF(2^{2k})$ be a primitive third root of unity. Let $a,b\in GF(2^{2k})$, $a\neq0$, be arbitrary. Then the recipe $\alpha_1=b$, $\alpha_j=b+a\omega^{j-2}$, $j=2,3,4$ should work. Of course, the element $\omega$ is already in the subfield $GF(4)$.

Comment: One warning: You cannot expect that $P(x)=x^4+e_3x+e_4$ would always have four zeros in $GF(2^{2k})$. You need $e_3$ to be a cube, and then you need to select $e_4$ so that $P(x)$ has at least one zero (when it will automatically have four). If you follow the recipe of the previous comment you should be ok.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate for your useful comment.

Comment: Excuse me, I thought you have seen my comment and that question and you did not want to make comment. I undeleted the question  now. Thanks.